# Google file picker returning 401 error

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Hi I am developing web application and i am trying to implement google file picker api. I have created project in google developer console. I have created API key and OAUTH 2.0 Client ID. I am following http://seanamarasinghe.com/developer/google-picker-with-drive/.

I have attached sample screen shot.
[image: Google Developer console]

When i upload files i get error The API developer key is invalid. I am running the application in localhost as http://localhost:11726/FilePicker.html.

I have entered http://localhost:11726in origin. Please find below screen shot. 
[image: Oauth]

May i get some help to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy. Remove    `.setDeveloperKey(developerKey)` code from your `createPicker()` function. I don't know why Google is adding this API here exactly, but it is not needed as you already have the OAuthClientID. If you remove that part, your quickstart sample will work.

[image]